# Python: How to create a log that updates the values of its message?

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I don't know what this kind of behavior is called so I couldn't find anything on google. What I want to accomplish is a fraction that shows how many jobs of the total have completed. Right now I can do this by simply `print('{}/{}'.format(str(count)/str(total)))`. I don't want a new line or a new print every time the value changes though, I want to change the value on the previous print. Basically would function like a loader status.

I'll try and show what Im talking about by these representations of the console.

What I have now

Update 1

```
> 1/30 done.
```

update 2

```
> 1/30 done.
> 2/30 done.
```

update 3

```
> 1/30 done.
> 2/30 done.
> 3/30 done.
```

**What I want**

Update 1

```
> 1/30 done.
```

update 2

```
> 2/30 done.
```

update 3

```
> 3/30 done.
```

Comment: You want to print to the console, but not have a line feed on each print?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes. I updated the description to be more clear by adding a representation of the console.

Comment: python 2: `print 'stuff\r',`

Comment: python 3: `print('stuff\r', end='')`

Comment: You might want to look at the [progressbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar) library.

Comment: Checkout http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576986-progress-bar-for-console-programs-as-iterator/